# Wordpress hueman theme with crayon syntax highlighting

Tags: wordpress, syntaxhighlighter

We use the hueman theme and the crayon syntaxhighlighter at our company blog. However we have a problem with the style of the code blocks.

For example: [A blogpost at our blog](http://blog.flavia-it.de/behavior-driven-development-wir-wissen-doch-was-wir-tun/)

At every second code block the css stylesheet seems corrupt. The striped lines have the wrong background color and are white instead of grey. When I turn of the striped line feature, every second code block is white.

Anyone know this issue? I search for several hours but I wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, tried adding the entry in the main.css file but it didn't solve it! (I'm no css expert or html programmer). Can you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it. Had ".entry table tr.alt" in my css which override the default crayon syntaxhighlighting style

Added:

```
.entry tr.crayon-row.alt {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

and now it works as expected :)